Server upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 re-connect to upgrade process
While upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04 via do-release-upgrade i had hit CTRL+C while being in a "configuration modified" "examine shell", which then dropped me back out of the shell, put up a bunch of python "KeyboardInterrupt" stacktraces and then i was in the shell i was before executing do-release-upgrade.
I wanted to re-connect which should have been over screen like in 20.04 to 22.04 (or to the .10 releases), where i had similar issues already (regarding the CTRL+C / KeyboardInterrupt), but this time i found that screen was not actually required in the upgrade as i didnt have it installed (and this time it didnt ask to install it or automatically install it).
Afterwards i looked if the process was still up, and yes the noble python process was still up with a idle bash shell, where i dont know of a way to re-connect to again.
After killing the bash shell, the upgrade process seemed to continue on in a "headless" mode and after some time there were some Z(ombie) processes which dont seem to affect to upgrade for now.
(also the upgrade seems to still be continuing and i am a bit too scared to just kill it)
So now my question: is it intentional that screen is no longer required (even though the noble python process was not started with --disable-gnu-screen), or if there is now a new way to re-connect to the noble process.
(Note: i already looked and the DistUpgradeViewText frontend still sets self.needs_screen = True)
PS: htop tree view says that the noble python process's parent is PID 1 (systemd in my case)
Environment: Ubuntu server 22.04 (upgraded before upgrading to 24.04), screen is not installed, system is a Raspberry Pi 3B. The upgrade was run via (ssh -> zsh -> tmux) (tmux -> zsh -> do-release-upgrade).
(tmux is in the mix as i also want a system monitor up while upgrading without having to-do multiple ssh-sessions and should be irrelevant to this question)

upgrade log snippet of the KeyboardInterrupt stacktraces:
2024-09-10 14:52:46,823 ERROR SystemError from cache.commit(): E:Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock. It is held by process 23578 (dpkg), W:Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system., E:Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
2024-09-10 14:52:47,604 ERROR not handled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 610, in install_archives
    def commit(

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ny0u7jj/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeView.py", line 229, in run
    res = os.WEXITSTATUS(self.wait_child())

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ny0u7jj/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeView.py", line 197, in wait_child
    select.select([self.statusfd], [], [], self.select_timeout)

KeyboardInterrupt


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ny0u7jj/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1846, in doDistUpgrade
    res = self.cache.commit(fprogress,iprogress)

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ny0u7jj/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 328, in commit
    apt.Cache.commit(self, fprogress, iprogress)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 664, in commit
    # reload the fetcher for media swaping

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 613, in install_archives
    install_progress: InstallProgress | None = None,

apt_pkg.Error: E:Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock. It is held by process 23578 (dpkg), W:Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system., E:Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ny0u7jj/noble", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ny0u7jj/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ny0u7jj/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2662, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ny0u7jj/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2626, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doDistUpgrade():

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ny0u7jj/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1881, in doDistUpgrade
    if not run_apport():

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ny0u7jj/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeApport.py", line 129, in run_apport
    return (subprocess.call("/usr/bin/apport-cli") == 0)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 347, in call
    return p.wait(timeout=timeout)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1209, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1959, in _wait
    (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1917, in _try_wait
    (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)

KeyboardInterrupt

2024-09-10 14:52:47,605 DEBUG running apport_crash()

also a small snippet about screen at the beginning:
2024-09-10 11:58:14,225 INFO screen could not be run
2024-09-10 11:58:14,565 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view

